# OpenGL -- glGenVertexArrays, "thread 1: exc_bad_access (code =1, address=0x0)"

Tags: c++, opengl, xcode8, exc-bad-access, glew

I am writing a **openGL program(C++)** which draws a ground with two 3D objects above it. The programming tool I use is **Xcode version 8.0(8A218a)**(OSX 10.11.6).

***my code(main.cpp):***

```
   #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>
    #include <glm/glm.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    using glm::vec3;
    using glm::mat4;

    GLint programID;
    //initialize all OpenGL objects
    GLuint groundVAO, groundVBO, groundEBO; //ground


    bool checkStatus( //OK
        GLuint objectID,
        PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC objectPropertyGetterFunc,
        PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC getInfoLogFunc,
        GLenum statusType)
        {
        GLint status;
        objectPropertyGetterFunc(objectID, statusType, &status);
        if (status != GL_TRUE)
        {
            GLint infoLogLength;
            objectPropertyGetterFunc(objectID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
            GLchar* buffer = new GLchar[infoLogLength];

            GLsizei bufferSize;
            getInfoLogFunc(objectID, infoLogLength, &bufferSize, buffer);
            cout << buffer << endl;

            delete[] buffer;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

     bool checkShaderStatus(GLuint shaderID) //OK
    {
        return checkStatus(shaderID, glGetShaderiv, glGetShaderInfoLog, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
    }

     bool checkProgramStatus(GLuint programID) //OK
    {
        return checkStatus(programID, glGetProgramiv, glGetProgramInfoLog, GL_LINK_STATUS);
    }

    string readShaderCode(const char* fileName) //OK
    {
        ifstream meInput(fileName);
        if (!meInput.good())
        {
            cout << "File failed to load..." << fileName;
            exit(1);
        }
        return std::string(
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(meInput),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
        );
    }

    void installShaders() //OK
    {
        GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        const GLchar* adapter[1];
        //adapter[0] = vertexShaderCode;
        string temp = readShaderCode("VertexShaderCode.glsl");
        adapter[0] = temp.c_str();
        glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
        //adapter[0] = fragmentShaderCode;
        temp = readShaderCode("FragmentShaderCode.glsl");
        adapter[0] = temp.c_str();
        glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);

        glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

        if (!checkShaderStatus(vertexShaderID) || 
    !checkShaderStatus(fragmentShaderID))
            return;

        programID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        glLinkProgram(programID);

        if (!checkProgramStatus(programID))
            return;

        glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);

        glUseProgram(programID);
     }

     void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
     {
         //TODO:
     }

     void sendDataToOpenGL()
     {
         //TODO:
        //create solid objects here and bind to VAO & VBO

        //Ground, vertices info
        const GLfloat Ground[]
        {
             -5.0f, +0.0f, -5.0f, //0
             +0.498f, +0.898, +0.0f, //grass color
             +5.0f, +0.0f, -5.0f, //1
             +0.498f, +0.898, +0.0f,
             +5.0f, +0.0f, +5.0f, //2
             +0.498f, +0.898, +0.0f,
             -5.0f, +0.0f, +5.0f
        };
        GLushort groundIndex[] = {1,2,3, 1,0,3};

        //Pass ground to vertexShader
        //VAO
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &groundVAO);
        glBindVertexArray(groundVAO);

        //VBO
        glGenBuffers(1, &groundVBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, groundVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Ground), Ground, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //EBO
        glGenBuffers(1, &groundEBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, groundEBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(groundIndex), groundIndex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //connectToVertexShader
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //position
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); //color
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (char*)(sizeof(float)*3));
     }

    void paintGL(void)
    {
        //TODO:
        //render your objects and control the transformation here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //translate model
        glm::mat4 modelTransformMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), vec3(+0.0f, +0.0f, -3.0f));
        //perspective view
        glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(+40.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, +60.0f);
        //ultimate matrix
        glm::mat4 ultimateMatrix;

        //register location on the graphics cards
        GLint ultimateMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ultimateMatrix");
        /*GLint modelTransformMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "modelTransformMatrix");
        GLint projectionMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "projectionMatrix");*/

        //drawing the ground

        /*glUniformMatrix4fv(modelTransformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelTransformMatrix[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);*/
        glBindVertexArray(groundVAO);
        ultimateMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelTransformMatrix;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ultimateMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &ultimateMatrix[0][0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        glFlush();
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void initializedGL(void) //run only once
    {
        glewInit();
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        sendDataToOpenGL();
        installShaders();
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        /*Initialization*/
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutCreateWindow("Try");
        glutInitWindowSize(700, 700);

        //const GLubyte* glversion = glGetString(GL_VERSION);

        /*Register different CALLBACK function for GLUT to response
        with different events, e.g. window sizing, mouse click or
        keyboard stroke */
        initializedGL();

        //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

        glutDisplayFunc(paintGL);
        glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

        /*Enter the GLUT event processing loop which never returns.
        it will call different registered CALLBACK according
        to different events. */
        //printf("OpenGL ver: %s\n", glversion);
        glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }
```

***VertexShaderCode.glsl:***

```
#version 430  // GLSL version your computer supports

in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec3 vertexColor;

uniform mat4 ultimateMatrix;

out vec3 theColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 v = vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = ultimateMatrix * v;
    theColor = vertexColor;
}
```

***FragmentShaderCode.glsl:***

```
#version 430 //GLSL version your computer supports

out vec4 theColor2;
in vec3 theColor;

void main()
{
    theColor2 = vec4(theColor, 1.0);
}
```

Functions: ***checkStatus, checkShaderStatus, checkProgramStatus, readShaderCode, installShaders*** should be all fine.

***void keyboard()*** can be ignored since I havent implemented it yet(just for keyboard control).

I implemented the object "Ground" in sendDataToOpenGL(). But when I compiled and ran the program, ***"thread 1: exc_bad_access (code =1, address=0x0)"*** occured in the line of ***VAO***:
[image]

And the pop-out window is just a white screen instead of a green grass(3d).
[image]

I have tried a method which was provided in other stackoverflow post: using `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. I didnt see any errors by using that, but the popout screen vanished immediately just after it appeared. It seems that it couldnt help the problem.

Can someone give me a help? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if I make my question clear enough. You can ask me for more details. Giving downvote without explanations is an awful behavior.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for your help, it looks much more clearer. :)

Comment: "By the way glutInitWindowSize should be called before glutCreateWindow"

OK, I switched them.

Then, I added these codes under "glutCreateWindow("Try");"(inside int main()) :

    if(glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_array_object") != GL_TRUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "It is not supported!\n");
    }

"It is not supported!" is printed out. Well, does it mean that the glGenvertexarray cant be supported?

Comment: I get:
1: glGenVertexArrays(1, &groundVAO); the error turns from "thread 1: exc_bad_access (code =1, address=0x0)" to "Thread 1:breakpoint1.1"

2. The statement in fprintf : "It is not supported!" was printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) is available in since OpenGL version 3.0. If vertex array objects are supported can be checked by `glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_array_object")`.

Glew can enable additional extensions by `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. See the [GLEW documantation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) which says:

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

Add this to your code:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
```

Comment: When you read from file, then the shader fiels have to be contained in the working directory of the application. For debug reasons you can appy an absolut file path to the call of `readShaderCode(...)`.