# Switching from OpenGL 2.1 with GLSL 1.2 to OpenGL 3.3 with GLSL version 1.5 breaks my code

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to switch my OpenGL version from OpenGL 2.1 to OpenGL 3.3. The minimal reproducible OpenGL 3.3 code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

static const GLuint WIDTH = 512;
static const GLuint HEIGHT = 512;
static const GLchar* vertex_shader_source =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec2 coord2d;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
static const GLchar* fragment_shader_source =
"#version 330\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
static GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0,  0.8,
    -0.8, -0.8,
    0.8, -0.8,
};

GLuint common_get_shader_program(
                                 const char *vertex_shader_source,
                                 const char *fragment_shader_source
                                 ) {
    GLchar *log = NULL;
    GLint log_length, success;
    GLuint fragment_shader, program, vertex_shader;

    /* Vertex shader */
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    log = (char*) malloc(log_length);
    if (log_length > 0) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, log_length, NULL, log);
        printf("vertex shader log:\n\n%s\n", log);
    }
    if (!success) {
        printf("vertex shader compile error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Fragment shader */
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    if (log_length > 0) {
        log = (char*)realloc(log, log_length);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, log_length, NULL, log);
        printf("fragment shader log:\n\n%s\n", log);
    }
    if (!success) {
        printf("fragment shader compile error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Link shaders */
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    if (log_length > 0) {
        log = (char*)realloc(log, log_length);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, log_length, NULL, log);
        printf("shader link log:\n\n%s\n", log);
    }
    if (!success) {
        printf("shader link error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Cleanup. */
    free(log);
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    return program;
}

int main(void) {
    GLint attribute_coord2d;
    GLuint program, vbo;
    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_GLContext gl_context;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(__FILE__, 0, 0,
                              WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    glewInit();

    /* Shader setup. */
    program = common_get_shader_program(vertex_shader_source, fragment_shader_source);
    attribute_coord2d = glGetAttribLocation(program, "coord2d");

    /* Buffer setup. */
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_coord2d, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Global draw state */
    glUseProgram(program);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    /* Main loop. */
    while (1) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord2d);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord2d);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }

    /* Cleanup. */
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteProgram(program);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gl_context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are no compile time errors and no runtime errors, but it only renders a blank screen. However, when I change `vertex_shader_source` to

```
"#version 120\n"
"attribute vec2 coord2d;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
```

`fragment_shader_source` to

```
"#version 120\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
```

and comment out the lines

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

the code works and I get the expected output.

[image]

It feels like the OpenGL 3.3 version of the code should work, especially considering there are very few differences between the two code snippets. I have also checked to make sure that the vertex buffer is being set correctly using `glGetBufferSubData`. As far as I can tell, it is being set correctly.

The only two possibilities I can think of are

1. There is something I do not understand about the vertex shader and/or fragment shader source code.
2. There is something wrong with my build process. I.e. a library is missing or not being linked.

Concerning the second possibility, I am using XCode on Mac OSX, and these are the libraries I am linking with.

[image]

Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: In core mode you **must have** a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default vertex array object "0" is not valid.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks. 

So do you mean I need to add something like   

`glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);` ?

I just tried that, and I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

Comment: @Rabbid76 Just figured it out, the answer to that issue was here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377012/1598568 (needed to add `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`)  Thanks! Your solution worked for me. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I wouldn't say its a duplicate, the main issue was not knowing that I needed a named Vertex Array Object in the first place. That was an answer about the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no compile time errors and no runtime errors, but it only renders a blank screen. However, when I change...

In core mode you must have a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default vertex array object "0" is not valid.

---

> So do you mean I need to add something like `glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);` `glBindVertexArray(vao);` ? I just tried that, and I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

[`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) is available in since OpenGL version 3.0. If vertex array objects are supported can be checked by `glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_array_object")`.

Glew can enable additional extensions by:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
```

See the [GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html):

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

Comment: The easy fix is to make a single VAO and bind it, and then proceed as usual.